# Connection timed out while copying ssh key from CentOS to Ubuntu using ssh-copy-id

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to copy my public key from a CentOS environment to a Ubuntu machine. I used the following command

```
ssh-copy-id root@Ubuntu_IP
```

However I get an error saying `Connection timed out`. I'm able to ping from my host to the remote machine. The purpose behind this is that my host machine is ansible control node where as Ubuntu machine is my managed node.

Comment: Are you able to ssh the remote machine? Are you sure about the ports and the firewall setup?

Comment: @Maximilan Kindshofer Nope I'm not able to ssh the remote machine..I use a ssh client and login to the same remote machine using the same port(22). So i guess the port is ok..i have manually disabled the firewall on ubuntu using iptables -F

Comment: @jugal there's some confusion here, your first sentence says you're not able to ssh to the machine, but your next sentence says you are.

Comment: the second ssh is a stand alone client software that i used to directly ssh into the remote machine using my local machine.(my ansible control node is different than my local machine).I know its a bit confusing and complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a permanent route in the remote machine for the host machine. 
 route add -net remote_ip netmask mask_ip gw gateway_ip eth0

Also disable the firewall on the remote machine. This seemed to have solved the problem in my case.